# How to schedule a import to database from bucket in google cloud?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I have a database on Gcloud, and every day I receive an actualization in my bucket. I want to schedule the import of this file (sql.gz) that i receive into my database.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Lots of options to get this done:

- Cron job
- Dataflow pipeline
- Cloud Function triggered on bucket change
- etc.